# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an'System.Web'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using VS Code to create a asp.net project. The issue was first brought up because I need to use AllowAnonymous action filter. It gave error of "`The type or namespace name 'AllowAnonymousAttribute' could not be found.`" So I added using System.Web.Mvc; at the beginning part. It showed the `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'` Could you give any suggestion? Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using DatingApp.API.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DatingApp.API.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        public ValuesController(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetValues()
        {
            var values=await _context.Values.ToListAsync();
            return Ok(values);
        }
```

.......

after run `dotnet watch run`, it gave errors as below.

```
watch : Started
Controllers\ValuesController.cs(4,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Xumin\projects\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj]
Controllers\ValuesController.cs(12,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AllowAnonymousAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Xumin\projects\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj]
Controllers\ValuesController.cs(12,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AllowAnonymous' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Xumin\projects\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did have using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; in the namespaces part. Do you know what's the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up technologies. The `System.Web` namespace and its children refer to the ASP.NET 4.x framework and you are creating an ASP.NET Core application.

[The AllowAnonymousAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.allowanonymousattribute) class that you are looking for is under the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` namespace:

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class AllowAnonymousAttribute : Attribute, IAllowAnonymous
    {
        public AllowAnonymousAttribute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Small thing, but it would be better to say that the namespace refers to the ASP.NET MVC framework or just ASP.NET in general, whereas the OP is using ASP.NET Core. An ASP.NET Core app can run on .NET 4.x, but you still wouldn't utilize `System.Web`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You have a point there, thanks. Updated to just `System.Web` as it encompasses the entire framework

Comment: Thank you that you would like to look into such a small problem. It's really stuck me for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace `System.Web.Mvc` is for ASP.NET in the :NET Framework. In ASP.NET Core the respective namespace is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization`. Check the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.allowanonymousattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.0) for more details.